# jQuery click event not binding to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, modal-dialog

I am building a Chrome Extension for Instagram.  My problem is occurring on the "single post" page of instagram (when you click on a post and it is shown as a modal).

When the post modal is showing I append a custom modal/pop-up of my own to the page with this code:

```
function attachUpgradePopup(str) {
    $(".upgrade-popup-container").remove();
    $("body").append(`
        <div class="upgrade-popup-container">
            <div class="upgrade-popup">
                <img class="popup-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/6sOdwYs.png">
                <p class="upgrade-popup-text">This post is ${str}.</p><br>
                <p class="upgrade-popup-text">To do this you must upgrade to</p>
                <p class="upgrade-popup-text">the PRO version!</p>
                <span class="popup-close">X</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    `);
    $(".popup-close").click(function() {
        console.log('closing')
        $(".upgrade-popup-container").remove();
    });
}
```

My problem is that the `click` function is not working on the `.popup-close` `span` for some reason.  I know that it has to do with the instagram post modal being open because I use this custom pop-up in other places/pages when there is no post modal open and it works great.  But when the instagram post modal is open the `.popup-close` `span` does nothing when I click it.

Why is this happening?

I know that it has nothing to do with `z-index` because I have tested that.  I feel like Instagram might be running some kind of jQuery in the background that is disrupting my `click` event from binding because even when I open both modals and then paste the `click` code straight into the console the `.popup-close` `span` still does nothing.

**UPDATE:** I have also tried event delegation for the `.popup-close` `span` and that does not work.

**UPDATE:** I have also tried to bind to the `.popup-close` `span` with vanilla javascript and that does not work.  It seems like nothing can bind to this element when the instagram post modal is up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('body').on('click', eventHandlerFunction);`

Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
function attachUpgradePopup(str) {
    $(".upgrade-popup-container").remove();
    $("body").append(`
        <div class="upgrade-popup-container">
            <div class="upgrade-popup">
                <img class="popup-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/6sOdwYs.png">
                <p class="upgrade-popup-text">This post is ${str}.</p><br>
                <p class="upgrade-popup-text">To do this you must upgrade to</p>
                <p class="upgrade-popup-text">the PRO version!</p>
                <span class="popup-close">X</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        `);
    $("body").on("click", ".popup-close", function () {
        console.log('closing')
        $(".upgrade-popup-container").remove();
    });
}
```

Basically `$("body")` will capture click and check if target element is matching ".popup-close".

Comment: p.s. `$(SELECTOR).append(...)` returns jQuery element of selector (if any). so you can even chain `.on('click', ...)` to it.